# Splitting a question that was answered in two opposite meanings

Tags: support

My [question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/105465/what-does-the-canonization-of-tanach-mean/105476?noredirect=1#comment352526_105476) was understood by two answers in two different ways - riki answered about implications, and Yaakov answered about reasons. Seemingly it wasn't phrased clearly enough.

I would like [you] to split the Q. into two and transfer each answer into a corresponding Q.

Is that possible [for you?] to do that?

Answer (score 4):

I think moderators can do it, albeit with some effort. (It requires deleting one answer, asking another question, closing the original question, merging the non-deleted answer to the new question, unlocking and reopening the closed question, and undeleting the deleted answer. And that only works if deleted answers don't get merged to other questions, which I think is true, but I'm not sure. Actually, I think all of that can be done by the community without a moderator except the merge, which I think is a moderator-only action.)

Personally, I don't plan to. Next time, ask a question clearly, and this won't happen.

Comment: Merging questions moves all answers; there's no way to split answers between the two questions.

Comment: @MonicaCellio even deleted ones?

Comment: I *think* so, but now that you raise the question, I don't think I've actually seen a test case.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I seem vaguely to recall actually doing the steps outlined in this answer and thereby splitting answers between questions. But I may well be misremembering.

Comment: [I thought you can’t undo a merge.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/468?m=44681179#44681179)

Comment: @Alex, you can't undo a merger, but I think maybe deleted answers aren't part of the merger to begin with, in which case there's nothing to undo: just to undelete the never-merged answer.